# get latitude & longitude zero while run app first time, but after 10 mins, it will get correct values. how to fix this?

Tags: android, gps

First time I am getting:

```
latitude:0.00
longitude:0.00
address: not found
```

After 10 mins I am getting:

```
latitude:13.00666178
longitude:80.25727619
address:some address
```

Comment: What is your question at first ? Don't forget to enable localization with Wifi if you can, if your are testing indoor without it, it might be long I guess

Comment: use a thread and check the lat and lon. if its zero, then again try for the location. if its not zero, then only excecute the next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            currentLat = location.getLatitude();
            currentLong = location.getLongitude();

        }
}
```

Add Appropriate permission too

Answer (score 0):

```
LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
location =locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
         location = googleMap.getMyLocation();
         if (location != null) {
            LatLng latLang = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLang, 17);
            googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
}
```